# How do I debug a 'java_binary' target executed by a Bazel rule via 'ctx.actions.run(...)'?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I have a `java_binary` target in my workspace that I'm later passing as an executable to `ctx.actions.run` inside the rule. So far so good.

Now I want to debug this `java_binary` while Bazel is executing the rule. In order to attach a debugger I need the `java_binary` run in debug mode. So far, the only thing I came up with is setting `jvm_flags` on the `java_binary`. I was able to get that to work. But I was wondering if there is a way to achieve it from the command line instead of baking it into the `java_binary`.

```
java_binary(
    ...
    jvm_flags = [
        "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000"
    ],
)
```

*Is it possible to achieve this from the command line without hard coding `jvm_flags`?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
bazel run //:my-target -- --debug
```

One strategy is to run the build with `--subcommands`, which will tell bazel to print out all the commands it's running during the build. Then find the command line corresponding to the invocation of the `java_binary` you're interested in. Then you can copy/paste that command (including the `cd` part) and modify it to include the debug flags, and debug it as you would any other process.

Note also that `java_binary` outputs a wrapper script that includes a `--debug[=<port>]` flag, so that should be all that needs to be added to the command line.

Note also that `--subcommands` will only print the commands that are actually executed during the build, so a fully cached / fully incremental build will print nothing. You may need to do a `clean`, or delete some of the outputs of the action you're interested in so that bazel runs that command.

Comment: That debug flag was all I needed, thanks `bazel run //:my-target -- --debug`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can pass the `--jvm_flag` option as part of the program options after the `--`.

BUILD:

```
java_binary(
    name = "extract",
    main_class = "com.pkg.Main",
    resources = glob(["src/main/resources/**/*"]),
)
```

CLI:

```
bazel run //:extract -- --jvm_flag="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7942" -path %cd%\config.json
```

It seems that the `--jvm_flag` option needs to come immediately after the `--`, before the program options (`-path` in the example).  This is with Bazel 3.7.0.

Comment: Turns out `--jvm_flag` is not needed. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works but if you're looking for a more complete command try running

```
bazel run --java_debug --test_arg=--wrapper_script_flag=--debug=8000 -- //your-target/...
```

You should see this in the Bazel logs

```
...
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
...
```

If you're running the command on a different host, you can reverse ssh tunnel using

```
ssh -L 8000:localhost:8000 <remote-host-cname>
```

Once you do this, just bind your debugger to port 8000 using this JVM flag

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000
```

This should do what you're looking for.